# force ember store to skip cache and get data from API call

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to understand how can I force ember store to make another api call instead of fetching records from cache when I use findAll. I know if records are already loaded then ember returns cached data unless asked to skip it. On doing some study (blogs, documentation and stack overflow), people has suggested to use reload: true flag with findAll but its not working for me. When I do a reload:true flag then store still returns me data from the cache.

If I am missing anything, then please help.

Code I have:

```
fetchStudentData() {
   this.get('store').findAll('student').then((response) => {
         return response.data;
   });
}
```

This function is tied to a button so on clicking I need to re-initiate the API call. I replaced the store call to use:

```
this.get('store').findAll('student', { reload: true }).then((response) => {
         return response.data;
   });
```

But this also didnt help as it still returned me old records in the store cache.

Comment: what code do you have at the moment?

Comment: Let me update the post with the code I have.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli any comments?

Comment: added answer, lemme know how it goes!

Comment: Could you describe your use case a little bit more in detail? Why do you want to enforce the reload? Is it about getting rid of records in store that are already deleted on API? As far as I know `this.store.findAll('my-model', { reload: true })` will enforce a reload but that will only update existing and add new records. It won't remove any record that is already in local store but not returned by API. Is this the issue you are facing?

Comment: yeah so what i want is to invalidate the cache and get fresh records from API call, I dont want findAll to append records returned by API to existing data in store. As per documentation it says findAll with reload: true will not take data from cache and will issue a new API call everytime

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the issue you are having, but if you don't care about your cache at all, you could do this:

```
async myMethod() {
  this.store.unloadAll('student');
  let students = await this.store.findAll('student');
}
```

Something that puzzled me about your query is that you're doing `response.data` inside your `then`, I know `data` is an attribute on the raw json payload, but all the `store` methods that return values return Models. So, you'll get student instances back instead of raw json (if you *want* raw json (I recommend against this), you can just use `fetch`).

Comment: response.data you can ignore as I was just giving an example and yeah store will convery them to models. But main problem is too invalidate the cache and hit API end point again. I tried unload all but its an async operation and somehow unload followed by new API call is not working

Comment: what isn't working? 
if unloadAll is async, just put an `await` before it

Comment: thanks but concern is documentation says to use reload:true flag so it shall issue another API request everytime a route having such call is loaded. But I only see it once when the route is loaded and after that everytime it takes from cache

Comment: I can try, its internal code so can not have the similar kind of pattern but I will try if I can put something almost similar. Bdw I tried putting consoles and never saw new API call after first time in network tab (also tested in mirage)